# Reference for Elliptical Basis Function Neural Networks

Tags: reference-request, neural-networks

I found the following assertion in a neural networks [FAQ](http://www.inf.ufsc.br/~patrec/FAQ2.html):

> Radial networks typically have only one hidden layer, but it can be
>   useful to include a linear layer for dimensionality reduction or
>   oblique rotation before the RBF layer

But I could not find any "formal" reference (published works) showing it. I found some papers describing EBFNN's, but they implement full covariance matrices on the RBF units. I could not find anything about this approach with an extra linear layer before the RBF layer. The theory is ok for me, it makes sense and works. What I need is any published work with this information. Is there one?

Comment: 1. Why do you need a published work?  2. Often these kinds of observations are made based upon experience so it's even possible it might just be folklore.

Comment: I want to use it in my own work and didn't want to leave it without any real reference. If I don't reference anything, it may have been published before and I fail to cite it. Other option would be to reference the FAQ itself, but I think some journals may see it as a bad practice (I really don't know).